# Java - Unresolved Compilation Problem creating multiple classes within a single file

Tags: java

I'm new at Java, and I'm practicing creating different classes within the same file, and them using them as objects. But when it compiled, it gives me an error on line 07. This is my code so far:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

package functions;

public class functions {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        functions fun = new functions();
        fun.Print("Hello World");
    }

    public void Print(String text) {
        System.out.print(text);
    }
}
```

The error in question is:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation
> problem: at functions.functions.main

I've tried to delete any class that were not main, I've tried to create the file without a package.

Comment: Recompile your code and check the Eclipse messages. This means your code failed to compile, but instead of just breaking, Eclipse "patches" the code to output this message. However, you need to look at the actual compilation error (which is probably the fact your `import` statement comes before the `package` declaration, which is the wrong order).

Answer (score 2):

The `package` declaration should come before the `import`.